# Finding most frequent variable for each ID in SAS

Tags: sas, frequency

My data set looks like this:

```
ID     X
769   "c"
769   "f"
769   "c"
1632  "a"
1632  "a"
1632  "b"
1632  "g"
1632  "a"
```

What I need is to find the most frequent X for each ID, so that the resulting data set would be:

```
ID     X
769   "c"
1632  "a"
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: proc sql max function works with character variables.

Comment: Did you mean "g" for ID = 1632? Lexicographically, "a" would be the lowest.

Comment: Not thinking lexicographical, asking about which letter appears the most.

Comment: What do you want returned if there are ties?

Comment: Haven't decided yet, but any one of the ties would be fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can use proc freq and a few more steps to get this done.

First, to create your data:

```
data have;
format id $10. x $1.;
infile datalines dsd missover dlm='|';
input id $ x $;
datalines;
769|c
769|f
769|c
1632|a
1632|a
1632|b
1632|g
1632|a
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by id;
run;
```

Now we are going to see the frequency of each X for ID, and output the results to the table "almost_want"

```
proc freq data=have;
by id;
tables x / out=almost_want;
run;
```

Then we subset only the values which X has the higher count:

```
proc sort data=almost_want;
by id count;
run;

data want;
    set almost_want;
    by id;
    if last.id then output;
run;
```

OBS: My Id variable is character, so you want to adjust it to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

PROC SQL MAX() Function works on character variables, so it's a quick solution.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select id, max(x) as max_a
from have
group by id;
quit;
```

EDIT: Alternative solution using BASE SAS and PROC SORT. Sort the data with a descending option and take the first record for each ID.

```
Proc freq data=have;
Table id*x/out=count;
 Run;

proc sort data=count;
by ID descending count;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id;
if first.id;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry, thought this worked, but what it really does is return the last letter alphabetically, not the most frequent letter. My initial question was poorly worded. I updated it. Is there a quick way to update your answer to fit?

Answer (score 0):

Re-consider a `proc sql` solution using derived table subquery:

```
proc sql;
   create table Output as   
   select id, x as freqx
   from
      (select id, x, count(x) as lettercount
       from example 
       group by id, x)  
   group by id
   having lettercount = max(lettercount);
quit;
```